# JDBC simplified connection

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any library that would simplify the task of connecting to a server with JDBC? Something that can take a string like `mysql://username:password@host/db`, similar to what `PHP MDB2` do as in [here](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2.html#methodparseDSN).

I'm not interested in any ORM or complex library such as `Spring` as I'm not even doing this from the `Java` language (but still on the JVM).

Comment: Not in Java, but on the JVM - interesting - are you doing it in bytecode or another language that is compiled down to bytecode?

Comment: Chris: The language was Clojure, which compiles to JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) from Spring.

```
static void jdbcTemplateExample() {
    DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .url(url)
            .build();

    JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

    List<Object> results = jt.query("SELECT * FROM table", (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
        //Create whatever Object you want with the resultSet.
        //Will convert to Map as example.
        Map results = new HashMap<>();
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
            results.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        return results;
    });

    //use the results
}
```